# Operator Overloading- how is the program flow

Tags: python-2.7, operator-overloading

```
class Vector:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
   self.a = a
   self.b = b

def __str__(self):
   return 'Vector (%d, %d)' % (self.a, self.b)

def __add__(self,other):
   return Vector(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)

v1 = Vector(2,10)
v2 = Vector(5,-2)
print v1 + v2
```

**Output:
Vector(7,8)**

**Hi There. I am new to coding. Could anyone please explain me the flow of the above program.
Thanks a lot.
P.S:Kindly do not down vote the question as I will be get blocked from asking any more. Thanks!!!**

Comment: The indentation is wrong, so currently you would get a syntax error. Ignoring that, `v1 + v2` is syntactic sugar for `v1.__add__(v2)`, which just calls `Vector.__add__(v1, v2)`. Hopefully that method is self explanatory.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the help.